# Flash Window size camera permissions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

If I make a the main flash window 100x100 or something small the permission dialog for audio video can't be shown in that space and flash automatically gives me the access denied error. Is there a way to allow for the permissions and then resize the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this but you will need to use JavaScript to handle resizing the `<div>` the swf is in.

You can use `ExtenalInterface` to call a js function from Flash.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

The AS3 code would be as simple as this:

```
ExternalInterface.call("myJSSwfResizeFunction");
```